# Unable to inject album art into m4a when converting from mp3 FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying so many variations of conversion for mp3 to M4A with album art injection via URL. The command below is written in `Go`, but runs directly in shell. I assume I need to parse the item in the stream differently or more explicitly specify jpg codec somehow, but at a loss.

```golang
    cmd = exec.Command(
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i",
        escapedInputPath,
        "-i",
        bookArt,
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-c:a",
        "aac",
        "-b:a",
        "256k",
        "-map",
        "0:0",
        "-map",
        "1:0",
        "-metadata:s:v",
        "title=Album cover",
        "-metadata:s:v",
        "comment=Cover (front)",
        escapedOutputPath,
    )
```

#### Error

```
 Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 05:54:05.07, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 64 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
Input #1, image2, from 'https://myimage.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17234 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 267x400 [SAR 300:300 DAR 267:400], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[ipod @ 0x119b04d30] Could not find tag for codec mjpeg in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
[aac @ 0x119b05ae0] Qavg: nan
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

The artwork stream needs to be signalled as an attached picture. Add `-disposition:v:0 attached_pic`